# Using ThreadPool to limit by memory usage in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an application that generates print jobs on individual threads so that the application's main thread isn't blocked. The problem I am running into is getting OutOfMemory exceptions when there are too many concurrent threads running. Using ThreadPool to limit number of concurrent threads does not help, for each print job's memory usage varies (i.e. some reports use heavy graphics and are thousands of pages long while others are two pages text only).

Is there a way to manage and idle new threads in a thread pool based on the total SIZE of the pool, not the number of threads?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can't determine the memory use of a specific thread as they all use the memory pools of their parent process, perhaps examine that metric before deciding to spin up a new thread.

Comment: Problem is that it's unknown at the start of the thread how much resources the thread will consume. For example, if five very large print jobs are sent simultaneously, the thread method will get working on them and keep growing on the heap until it crashes with OutOfMemory exceptions.

Comment: Then don't send them simultaneously.  Add them to a queue or something and process them one at a time in the worker thread.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, I'm dealing with inpatient users. It's a busy print shop, and as soon as a printer is idle, they want to send a job.

Comment: This is an issue with process memory? i.e there are sufficient free resources on the machine itself when this exception is thrown?  If so perhaps spin up a new process instead of a new thread.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I guess that will be the workaround here.

Comment: @jjthebig1, are you running your spooler on a 32-bit or 64-bit OS?

Comment: The build is set for x86 because of some old COM library that only works on 32-bit.